# Position text at the bottom of its containing div

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to place `<h1>` inline with `<h2>`. I can get them inline, but I can't seem to get the text in the both of them to sit at the bottom of their containers (`<h1>` and `<h2>`). What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/MmB3X/

Answer (score 3):

on your `h1` and `h2` elements, remove the float. Set them to `display: inline;` and in the containing `div` set `vertical-align: text-bottom;`

I [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MmB3X/13/) and it shows it correctly.

Comment: So by displaying them inline, I don't need float?

Comment: Nope. Setting `h1` and `h2` as `display: inline` - when they're normally `display: block` - makes them act as if you had wrapped them in `span` instead. But they have the benefit of still being semantically described as headers in this instance.

Comment: You may or may not need it, but keep in mind that `display: inline-block` preserves block capabilities such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings.

Answer (score 2):

No need to float the elements, can just change the CSS for your headings to:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: baseline;
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/MmB3X/8/

You can add padding to the `h2` , so it will be at the bottom, if this is what you want.

```
#photos-page-head h2 {
    ...
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    ...
}​
```

Comment: That's kind of hacky and the padding would need to be adjusted if the font sizes ever change.

Comment: You are right, but it still solves his problem :D Not the best solution, but one of them.